# Different Fragments showing the same content

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've created an activity with three fragments .the first fragment works fine , the second too , but the third shows the same content as the second fragment .

I don't see where the problem is , I have : ( where deletecase is the 3rd fragment xml file )

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deletecase, container, false);
```

and for the second :

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.updatecase, container, false);
```

and for each fragment I have a nested class .

How can I solve this ?

**EDIT**

I just relised that I forgot to do this :p

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a NewCaseFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

            if (position == 0) {
                Fragment fragment = new NewCaseFragment();
                // Bundle args = new Bundle();
                // args.putInt(NewCaseFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position +
                // 1);
                // fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;

            } else if (position == 1){
                Fragment fragment = new UpdateFragment();
                return fragment;
            }

            else {
                Fragment fragment = new DeleteFragment();
                return fragment;
            }
        }
```

thanks all for your answers .

Comment: I don't see you are doing a commit any where in the code?

Comment: It's the method inside the SectionsPagerAdapter class gernerated when creating a default fragment activity , I just forgot to check it :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify if the design is the same, but the ids are differents?

Comment: it could be an error in the R file. Try to create another layout and copy the design, and the you reference in the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

What about the main layout, the one with three fragment. Are you sure the android:name (or class) attribute are different for the second and the third fragments ?